# Rename Index Dynamically

Tags: sql-server, indexing, concatenation, rename

Im trying to do something like this (Replacing '-' with '_' on IndexName), But do not know how to achieve a correct concatenation

```
DECLARE @TestTable varchar(50) ='TableTest'

DECLARE @TestDatabase varchar(30) ='DatabaseTest'

DECLARE @TestIndex VARCHAR(150) ='NonClusteredIndex-20150617-075305'

DECLARE @TestSchema VARCHAR(20) ='SChemaTest'

EXEC sp_rename N'[' + @TestSchema + '].['+@TestTable+'].['+ @TestIndex +']'

, REPLACE( @TestIndex,'-','_')

, N'INDEX'
```

Any Help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: I think you need Dynamic SQL to do this. `sp_rename` doesn't like the concatenation.

Comment: You can't perform the replicate and concatenation when executing the proc. Assign the desired values to the variables and then execute `sp_rename`.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you. Be aware that you will get the `Caution` message.
`Caution: Changing any part of an object name could break scripts and stored procedures.` after you run this script.

```
DECLARE @TestTable varchar(50) ='TableTest'

DECLARE @TestDatabase varchar(30) ='DatabaseTest'
Declare @NewTestIndex varchar(150)
DECLARE @TestIndex VARCHAR(150) ='NonClusteredIndex-20150617-075305'
Set @NewTestIndex = Replace(@TestIndex,'-','_')

DECLARE @TestSchema VARCHAR(20) ='SChemaTest'
Declare @cmd varchar(max) 
Set @cmd = 'EXEC sp_rename N''[' + @TestSchema + '].['+@TestTable+'].['+ @TestIndex +']'', N''' +@NewTestIndex + ''', N''INDEX'''

Select @cmd

Execute (@cmd)
```

Comment: That's what im looking for.
Works PERFECT !!!!.
Thank you so much ( i need to take practice on dynamic querys )   
:(